# Magento can't create system backup

Tags: backup

So I've manage to create a Database backup no problem.
But when I tried to a System backup, it would show the little spinning icon then after a few minutes it would dissappear, leaving no create system backup.

When I look at the backend via Dreamweaver, it showed a 'temp' file. 
[image]

Is there something I should be doing?

Comment: a lot of possible reasons, but its most likely a simple php timeout

Comment: Using PHP to make a backup is simply a bad idea, because PHP is not made to do this. Better use mysql_dump and tar on the bash (ssh).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the cPanel access or, even if you have the server itself, you can take the system backup by just `compressing your magento root directory`, of which you can use to migrate your site to another server or, restore the magento if any undesirable crash occurs.